# If projects only use conda environments, why install anaconda?

Tags: anaconda, conda

I don't understand the purpose of installing all of anaconda as the 'root'. Assuming I'm using a conda environment for each project, why would the project need the 'root' contents?

Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I think this can only be answered by an employee of Continuum, but I would guess that its for people that only use the root environment, or who primarily use the root environment.